# .NET Core 2.0 View Component Not Populating @Model Property

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm learning how to use .NET Core 2.0, and one of the parts of it that I need to be able to use is a View Component.

I've almost figured it out completely. I'm using Dependency Injection to pass a service into my ViewComponent constructor which then passes off a List of `TestItem`to the view.

The `@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Common.TestItem>` property is always `null`, however; `ViewContext.ViewData.Model` populates correctly.

Any ideas why? Code is posted below.

---

**Service**

`TestItemService` class

```
public class TestItemService
    {
        public List<TestItem> GetItems()
        {
            return new List<TestItem>()
            {
                new TestItem(){ id=0, date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2), Name="TestItem1" },
                 new TestItem(){ id=1, date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4), Name="TestItem2" },
                  new TestItem(){ id=2, date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(3), Name="TestItem3" },
            };
        }
    }
```

**Dependency Injection**

In the `Startup` class in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddScoped<TestItemService.TestItemService, TestItemService.TestItemService>();
```

**ViewComponent**

```
public class TestViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly TestItemService.TestItemService service;
    public TestViewComponent(TestItemService.TestItemService context)
    {
        service = context;
    }


    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        List<TestItem> items = await GetItemsAsync();
        return View("Default",items);
    }
    public Task<List<TestItem>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        return service.GetItems().Where(i => i != null).ToAsyncEnumerable().ToList();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@page
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Common.TestItem>




<h3>Priority Items</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in (List<Common.TestItem>)ViewContext.ViewData.Model)
    {
        <li>@todo.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: I think `ViewContext.ViewData.Model` should just be `Model`

Comment: It returns null if I just use Model. @Joe

Comment: Do you have a view cshtml file and a view component cshtml file?

Comment: I have a .cs file for the c# and a .cshtml file for the view. 
[img](https://imgur.com/a/uX0QZf1) @Joe

Comment: I followed the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1) as well as other guides for doing the dependency injection. 
I'm also not using MVC.

Comment: I mean a controller when I say MVC. Technically I'm using the Model-View portion of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In my view component cshtml file, I had the `@page` tag at the top which for some reason broke this. I'll change the accepted answer to someone else's if they will explain ***why*** that broke it. What does the `@page` tag do>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio might clarify that a bit